# Search for XCUIElement is too slow

Tags: xcode, xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest, xcuielement

I am using XCUITest for UI-based testing of an iOS app.

A major (almost showstopping) problem in the project is performance when searching for elements in the visual tree.

**Exemplification:**

Front-screen of app consists of a stack of horizontal sliders containing about 20 views each. Each of these (slider) child views are itself a complex view with a deep hierarchy.

At the top of all this there is a button or two which must be tapped as part of the test.

When app is loading and sliders are not populated yes, it takes about 2-4 seconds to search and get an XCUIElement to a button in the screen's top. When app is finish loading and all sliders are populated, it takes a minut. **BIG PROBLEM**.

Therefore, I am convinced that it is the amount of elements in the visual tree that slows down the process.

I have tried a lot of different approaches to speed up the search, but all in vain.

**What have been tried:**

1. Normal approach like: app.buttons["name of button"].tap()
2. Same as 1, but get XUIElement before app loads
3. Use XCUIXoordinates

Comment: A debugDescription output would be very helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

You can speed up things by using firstMatch. It will stop searching the UI tree asap.

```
app.buttons["name of button"].firstMatch().tap()
```

This code will tap **the first** button or fail (because there is no matching button(s)), while the code you send will tap **the only** button or fail (because there are no buttons or more than one)